# How to bind physical nic to send a ip package with golang?

Tags: windows, go, ip, nic

I set up a virtual network card(TUN) on the windows client for the vpn to get traffic. When capturing virtual NIC traffic, I perform the following resource judgment logic: When accessing certain resources, the traffic (IP packets) will not be sent through the VPN channel.  I want to send the traffic (IP packets) directly through the physical NIC.
The problem now is how do I get the traffic sent directly through the physical network card.

--SYSTEM：WINDOWS
--LANGUAGE：GOLANG

I tried to simulate TCP/UDP by parsing IP packets and binding network adapter addresses for sending, but this was too slow.
Is there a way to directly bind the physical NIC and send IP packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw sockets are disabled since Windows XP, so you need third party software to inject IP packets.

I used WinPcap library for this. The Go binding exists: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap

The function that writes Ethernet frames to the datalink is [`Handle.WritePacketData`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap#Handle.WritePacketData)

The steps are:

1. Create a handle to your physical NIC with [`OpenLive`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap#OpenLive)
2. Wrap IP packed into datalink layer frame
3. Write the frame to the handle with `Handle.WritePacketData`

The tricky part with the step 1 is the name of the interface. In windows there are no such names as `eth0`. The required name looks like `\Device\NPF_{BBECCD43-3F2B-4594-B17B-5F38E73787E8}`

To get the proper names of the devices you can query `FindAllDevs` function. As `Administrator`!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func main() {
    // Get device list - run as ADMINISTRATOR!
    devices, err := pcap.FindAllDevs()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Print device information
    fmt.Println("Devices:")
    for _, device := range devices {
        fmt.Println("-----------------------")
        fmt.Println("Name: ", device.Name)
        fmt.Println("Description: ", device.Description)
        fmt.Println("Addresses: ", device.Description)
        for _, address := range device.Addresses {
            fmt.Println("  IP address: ", address.IP)
            fmt.Println("  Netmask: ", address.Netmask)
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output (this is my WiFi adapter):

```
-----------------------
Name:  \Device\NPF_{BBECCD43-3F2B-4594-B17B-5F38E73787E8}
Description:  Microsoft
Addresses:  Microsoft
  IP address:  fe80::de52:6717:446:57a1
  Netmask:  <nil>
  IP address:  172.30.1.95
  Netmask:  ffffff00
```

Comment: Thanks～ I had used the 'gopacket/pcap' package before, but had trouble using the 'handler.ReadPacketData()' method.
This method does not block the delivery of data packets to the corresponding process. When I read the data, the data has already been sent to the original process, and it does not allow me to change the destination address of the data to the virtual network card and send it.

Comment: @culionBear then you know better. I worked with `pcap` using C, never tried Go binding.